# Create firebase rules for dynamic and static nodes with exception fields

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have static nodes like (users-technical-services-orders),

for example (technical) I created (write restrict) to only same technical, except 3 fields be allowed to write for all users which have authenticated.

I can do it like this:

```
    {
    "rules": {
     //
    "phonenumbers":{
    ".read": true,
    ".write":  "auth !== null"
    },
    "services":{
    ".read": true,
    ".write":  "auth !== null"
    },
    "subservices":{
    ".read": true,
   ".write":  "auth !== null"
    },
    "ChargeRecordsProv":{
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write":  "auth !== null"
  },
    "ChargeRecordsUsers":{
    ".read": "auth !== null",
     ".write":  "auth !== null"
  },
    "ExchangeRecords":{
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write":  "auth !== null"
  },
     "directions":{
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write":  "auth !== null"
  },
     "orders":{
    ".read": "auth !== null",
     ".write":  "auth !== null"
  },
     "setting":{
    ".read": "auth !== null",
  },
     "technical":{
    ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$user_id": {
    ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
     },
     "balancepro": {
    ".write": "auth !== null"
     },
     "ratingNumClinets": {
    ".write": "auth !== null"
     },
     "ratingDegree": {
    ".write": "auth !== null"
     },
     "statusProv": {
    ".write": true
     }
  },
     "users":{
    ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$user_id": {
    ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
  }
  }
    }
  }
```

This is work good for my static nodes.

**the problem is:**

I have a dynamic nodes like (Technicians_Carpenter_location) which his name can not be known, because it depended on what the admin can set.

these dynamic nodes will be not allowed to read or write with my previous rules.
 if I add a public rules like this:

```
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      ".write":  "auth !== null"
```

It can be read and write but this will effect on all previous rules for static nodes and will not be work.

So, please make a suggestion, what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a [wildcard rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments), which matches all child nodes that are not matched by any other rule. A simple example of such a rule is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "profiles": {
      "$profileid": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the above rule, anyone can read a specific profile (for example `/profiles/puf`), but nobody can read all profiles at once (`/profiles`).

So in your case, if you want to grant specific permissions to specific named nodes, and a common set of permissions to all other nodes, you'd add a wildcard to your current nodes. Something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "phonenumbers":{
      ".read": true,
      ".write":  "auth !== null"
    },
    ...
    "$other": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      ".write":  "auth !== null"
    }
  }
}
```